# How to edit Sony Xperia J dictionary

Tags: sony-xperia, dictionary, text-prediction, sony-xperia-j

I like to use the built-in dictionary that suggests words when I use SMS or Hangouts.
It works okay but I'd like to edit some of the words it suggests.

Where can I edit the built-in dictionary? Is there a function for it?

Comment: I don't know for the Xperia, but usually this is bound to the keyboard you're using. So I'd start checking there (*Settings › Languages & Input*, click the "gear" symbol next to the keyboard, and check its settings). On my Optimus (stock 4.1.2) with the stock LG keyboard, I only can delete all user-entries; for others I've seen you can remove single words, and maybe you can even add single words there with some.

Comment: There is no dictionary settings in the input preferences (there is a custom dictionary that is empty). It seems that Sony doesn't like to allow customization in their phones (you can't block a phone number, you can't edit the  dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

Xperia: you can hold on the word displayed  and u have an option to delete it. 
You can add words by going through 'language & input' then add your words in 'personal dictionary'.

I would like to edit from a 'list' of saved words but I haven't found my way to the list.

Comment: That list is what we're looking for... I don't know what you mean by 'hold on the word displayed'. The suggestions cannot be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

open this PDF file and go start reading from page 23 (right column) about how to access the user dictionary. The instructions of editing user dictionary are on page 25 (right column). hope this helps.
http://help.mb.softbank.jp/xperia-z3/pdf/xperia-z3_en_userguide.pdf

Comment: you should post the answers yourself in the answers section, not just link them to an outside file for the user to find. if in the future that file would be removed, your answer would become worthless and downvoted.

Comment: More specifically, 27th page of the PDF file. Try editing the answer to show the infomation that you linked.